# Http Request base on priority using AngularJs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, http

I am sending multiple http request using Angularjs.

Can we set priority for some requests.

I am keep sending http request according to my need.  I can't send request  http request on sequence basis

Can somehow we can set **priority**

Any Idea?

Thanks

Comment: What do you exactly mean with priority? You can send requests on sequence basis btw.

Answer (score 0):

Hey id suggest you use a http Intercepter Service there you can monitor every request and response smth like this this is just an idea

```
.factory('httpInterceptor', function ($q, $rootScope, $filter) {
var canceller = $q.defer();
var numLoadings = 0;
var serialRequests = false;
var timeO;
var time1;
var loadingbar = { loading: "<progress value='?' max='10'></progress>" };
var loadingspinner = { loading: '<ion-spinner icon="crescent"></ion-spinner>' };

return {
    request: function (config) {

        if (config.url.indexOf('http') > -1 && config.url.indexOf('UpdateDeviceOnlineState') == -1 && config.url.indexOf('maps.googleapis') == -1) {
            console.log(config);
            //timeout if request takes longer than 15 sec spinner is removed request is cancelled and alert is called
            //config.timeout = canceller.promise;
            //var time1 = setTimeout(function () {
            //    canceller.resolve('Unauthorized');
            //    $rootScope.$broadcast("all_requests_done");
            //    alert('keine verbindung');
            //}, 15000);

            numLoadings++;
            if (serialRequests == false) {
                //if (config.url.indexOf('http') > -1) {
                //    loadingbar.percent = numLoadings;
                //    $rootScope.$broadcast("open_requests", loadingbar);
                //} else {
                //    $rootScope.$broadcast("open_requests", loadingspinner);
                //}
                $rootScope.$broadcast("open_requests", loadingspinner);
            } else {
                clearTimeout(timeO);
            }
        }

        return config || $q.when(config)
    },
    response: function (response) {

        if (response.config.url.indexOf('http') > -1 && response.config.url.indexOf('UpdateDeviceOnlineState') == -1 && response.config.url.indexOf('maps.googleapis') == -1) {
            //clearTimeout(time1);
            serialRequests = true;
            numLoadings--;

            timeO = setTimeout(function () {
                serialRequests = false
                if ((numLoadings) === 0) {
                    $rootScope.$broadcast("all_requests_done");
                }
            });
        }
        return response || $q.when(response);
    },
    responseError: function (response) {

        if (response.config.url.indexOf('http') > -1 && response.config.url.indexOf('UpdateDeviceOnlineState') == -1 && response.config.url.indexOf('maps.googleapis') == -1) {
            serialRequests = true;
            numLoadings--;

            timeO = setTimeout(function () {
                serialRequests = false
                if ((numLoadings) === 0) {
                    $rootScope.$broadcast("all_requests_done");
                }
            });
        }
        return $q.reject(response);
    }
};
})
```

But i think you have to work with promises here. $http has a timeout Property, which you can use to prioritize / sort your requests

[$http docs for timeout](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)